# PostgreSQL 9.3: Prepare dynamic string

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to prepare a dynamic string using the function.

There are two main stings in this: one is passing to the function and
other one is present in the function. The output string will be changes
according to the passing string to the function.

**Example**:

I have string `string1` which will pass to the the function. And `string2`
is present in the function.

One string that is `string2` is present in the function:

```
string2 = 'A1,A2,A3,A4'
```

And string that is `string1` I am passing to the function:

```
string1 = 'A1'
```

Then the expected prepared string should lookes like:

```
A1 = 1 AND A2 IS NULL AND A3 IS NULL AND A4 IS NULL
```

For the above result I have written the folling function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test(string1 varchar)
RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
    string2 varchar = 'A1,A2,A3,A4';
    string3 varchar;
    string4 varchar;
    string5 varchar;
    string6 varchar;
BEGIN
    string3 := REPLACE(string1,',',' = 1 AND ')||' = 1';

    RAISE INFO '%',string3;

    string4 := REPLACE(string2,string1,string3);

    RAISE INFO '%',string4; 

    string5 := REPLACE(string4,'1,',' 1 AND ');

    string6 := REPLACE(string5,',', ' IS NULL AND ')||' IS NULL ';

    RAISE INFO '%',string6; 
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Calling FUNCTION

```
SELECT f_test('A1');
```

Result:(Right)

```
A1 =  1 AND A2 IS NULL AND A3 IS NULL AND A4 IS NULL
```

**But** got stuck when pass `A4`

```
SELECT f_test('A4');
```

Result:(Wrong)

```
A 1 AND A2 IS NULL AND A3 IS NULL AND A4 =  1
```

While I was expecting:

```
A1 IS NULL AND A2 IS NULL AND A3 IS NULL AND A4 =  1
```

If I call:

```
SELECT f_test('A2,A4');
```

Then result should be:

```
A1 IS NULL AND A2 = 1 AND A3 IS NULL AND A4 =  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test(string1 varchar)
RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
    string2 varchar = 'A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7';
    string3 varchar;
    string4 varchar;
    string5 varchar;
    string6 varchar;
    intCount int;
BEGIN
    string3 := REPLACE(string1,',',' = 1 AND ')||' = 1';

    RAISE INFO '%',string3;

    string4 := REPLACE(string2,string1,string3);

    RAISE INFO '%',string4; 
select string_agg(c,' AND ') into  string6 from (
select  * from (
select c ||'= 1' c from (
select regexp_split_to_table(string2,',') c
)t 
where c in (select regexp_split_to_table(string1,','))
union all 
select c ||' IS NULL ' c from (
select regexp_split_to_table(string2,',') c
)t 
where  c  not in (select regexp_split_to_table(string1,','))
) t group by c order by c 
)t;
    RAISE INFO '%',string6; 
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Call : -  `select f_test('A3,A5')` or `select f_test('A3,A5,A2,A6')`

Comment: There is no `AND`. Please go through again.

Comment: @MAK did you test my answer ??

Comment: I am expecting the output like `A1 IS NULL AND A2 IS NULL AND A3 IS NULL AND A4 =  1 `.

Comment: @MAK ohh I got will fix soon :D

Comment: And one more thing. You have used `regexp_split_to_table('1,2,3,4', ',')::INT c1` in your script. But I am getting `string2` from other table which is not fixed.

Comment: @MAK you can pass `string2 ` like this  `regexp_split_to_table(string2 , ',')::INT c1` ,

Comment: Just try your script by passing one more value in `string2` at the declaration section. That is `A1,A2,A3,A4,A5`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73401/discussion-between-mak-and-unique-id).

Comment: @MAK `Just try your script by passing one more value in string2 at the declaration section. That is A1,A2,A3,A4,A5`  OH yeah , but you must give all the details in your question,

Comment: @unique_I'd, Sorry for late reply. Just check by passing 'A3,A5'.

Comment: Please check with the select f_test('A3,A5').

Comment: @MAK I worked out with the exact thing that you're mentioned in OP,but you're giving more info. after each update.So confused

Comment: Oh! I am really sorry for that. This is the last test.

Comment: @MAK is it possible to pass like `select f_test('A1','A5')
` instead of `select f_test('A1,A5')`,If *yes* I can quickly give you an answer

Comment: Oh! So you wanna pass the two parameters for that?

Comment: @MAK _Oh! So you wanna pass the two parameters for that?_ > I don't think so :D !!